# How to get the sum where cell reference is got using vlookup

Tags: excel

I have a list of names from rows 2 to 10 and Months names in columns from Jan to Dec. There are values in numerics from cell B2 to end.
I have a drop down list cell in another sheet containing months names.
I want to get the sum of values according to the month selected. For e.g. If June is choosen in drop down list, sum of values from Jan to June for that particular name should be calculated and shown in that cell. I want to get using Sum and vlookup function. Another e.g. if April is choosen, sum of values from Jan to April must be calculated for that particular name. I am providing a link to the images so that you can get a detailed view of my data.
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1z2tG-jU849BxCVFwHkOEfyYAOa5oatHe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INDEX/MATCH would be better suited:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(P2,A:A,0)):INDEX(A:M,MATCH(P2,A:A,0),MATCH(Q2,1:1,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: It is not working under my scenario. They are not month actually it is in dates like 01-01-2016, 01-02-2016.

Comment: And they are in Financial years way. Two Financial years are included

Comment: Then you need to provide more detail about your setup, include a picture of your data and expected output.  Add this to your original post not in comments.  Obviously we do not understand your requirements.

Comment: Hi...scott, i am providing a link to my inages so that you can get a detail view of my data. Thanks for your help.                                                                                          https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1z2tG-jU849BxCVFwHkOEfyYAOa5oatHe

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `OFFSET` function, e.g.

`=SUM(OFFSET(B1,MATCH("barry",A2:A10,0),0,1,MATCH("May",B1:M1,0)))`

....or if you really want to use `VLOOKUP` try this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP("barry",A2:M10,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MATCH("May",B1:M1,0)))+1,0))`